# Showing ProgressBar while uploading files in Android using OkHttp3

Tags: android, rest, amazon-s3, android-asynctask, okhttp

I am trying to upload files in Amazon S3 using OkHttp3 library. I am able to upload the files using `AsyncTask`.Right now, I am showing a normal `ProgressDialog`. But, I want to replace the `ProgressDialog` with a `ProgressBar`. For this, I am doing the following things, but somehow it does not work:

1) Creating a custom `ResponseBody` and `ProgressListener`:

```
private static class ProgressResponseBody extends ResponseBody {

    private final ResponseBody responseBody;
    private final ProgressListener progressListener;
    private BufferedSource bufferedSource;

    public ProgressResponseBody(ResponseBody responseBody, ProgressListener progressListener) {
        this.responseBody = responseBody;
        this.progressListener = progressListener;
    }

    @Override
    public MediaType contentType() {
        return responseBody.contentType();
    }

    @Override
    public long contentLength() {
        return responseBody.contentLength();
    }

    @Override
    public BufferedSource source() {
        if (bufferedSource == null) {
            bufferedSource = Okio.buffer(source(responseBody.source()));
        }
        return bufferedSource;
    }

    private Source source(Source source) {
        return new ForwardingSource(source) {
            long totalBytesRead = 0L;

            @Override
            public long read(Buffer sink, long byteCount) throws IOException {
                long bytesRead = super.read(sink, byteCount);
                // read() returns the number of bytes read, or -1 if this source is exhausted.
                totalBytesRead += bytesRead != -1 ? bytesRead : 0;
                progressListener.update(totalBytesRead, responseBody.contentLength(), bytesRead == -1);
                return bytesRead;
            }
        };
    }
}

interface ProgressListener {
    void update(long bytesRead, long contentLength, boolean done);
}
```

2) Implementing the ProgressListener interface within the AsyncTask using for uploading the files:

```
final ProgressListener progressListener = new ProgressListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void update(long bytesRead, long contentLength, boolean done) {
                        Log.d(AppGlobal.TAG, " " + bytesRead);
                        Log.d(AppGlobal.TAG, " " + contentLength);
                        Log.d(AppGlobal.TAG, " " + done);
                        Log.d(AppGlobal.TAG, (100 * bytesRead) / contentLength + " % done ");
                        Log.d(AppGlobal.TAG, " " + "-------------------------");
                    }
                };
```

3) Creating a OkHttp client and passing the progressListener created in Step 2 using a network interceptor:

```
Request request = new Request.Builder()
                        .header("Proxy-Authorization", "Basic " +     Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.NO_WRAP))
                        .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream")
                        .addHeader("Connection", "Keep-Alive")
                        .url(url)
                        .put(RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/octet-stream"), file))
                        .build();

OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                        .connectTimeout(1000, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                        .writeTimeout(1000, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                        .readTimeout(3000, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                        .proxy(proxy)
                        .proxyAuthenticator(proxyAuthenticator)
                        .addNetworkInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
                            @Override public okhttp3.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                                okhttp3.Response originalResponse = chain.proceed(chain.request());
                                return originalResponse.newBuilder()
                                        .body(new ProgressResponseBody(originalResponse.body(), progressListener))
                                        .build();
                            }
                        })
                        .build();

okhttp3.Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

But, the Log.d() statements used in the "update()" function of progressListener never gets executed.
If I can get these Log statements to print, then I can update the progress bar accordingly. Can someone kindly help me out.

Here is the full code used in "doInBackground" method of AsyncTask:

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(File... inputs) {
try {
    file = inputs[0];
    Date expiration = new Date();
    long milliSeconds = expiration.getTime();
    milliSeconds += 1000 * 60 * 60; // Add 1 hour.
    expiration.setTime(milliSeconds);


    GeneratePresignedUrlRequest generatePresignedUrlRequest =
            new GeneratePresignedUrlRequest(Constants.BUCKET_NAME, AppGlobal.deviceId + "/" + file.getName());
    generatePresignedUrlRequest.setMethod(HttpMethod.PUT);

    generatePresignedUrlRequest.setContentType("application/octet-stream");

    generatePresignedUrlRequest.setExpiration(expiration);

    final URL url = Util.getS3Client(UploadActivity.this).generatePresignedUrl(generatePresignedUrlRequest);

    Log.d("DXXXXXX", " URL    ->    " + url);

    String domain = AppGlobal.getDomain(UploadActivity.this);
    int port = Integer.valueOf(AppGlobal.getPort(UploadActivity.this));
    final String signature = AppGlobal.getSignature(UploadActivity.this);


    Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP,
            InetSocketAddress.createUnresolved(domain, port));//the proxy server(Can be your laptop ip or company proxy)

    try {

        String headerVal = String.format("%s:%s", "vzServices", signature);
        final byte[] data = headerVal.getBytes("UTF-8");

        okhttp3.Authenticator proxyAuthenticator = new okhttp3.Authenticator() {
            @Override
            public Request authenticate(Route route, okhttp3.Response response) throws IOException {

                String credential = Credentials.basic("vzServices", signature);
                return response.request().newBuilder().header("Proxy-Authorization", credential).build();
            }
        };


        final ProgressListener progressListener = new ProgressListener() {
            @Override
            public void update(long bytesRead, long contentLength, boolean done) {
                Log.d(AppGlobal.TAG, " " + bytesRead);
                Log.d(AppGlobal.TAG, " " + contentLength);
                Log.d(AppGlobal.TAG, " " + done);
                Log.d(AppGlobal.TAG, (100 * bytesRead) / contentLength + " % done ");
                Log.d(AppGlobal.TAG, " " + "-------------------------");
            }
        };


        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .header("Proxy-Authorization", "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.NO_WRAP))
                .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream")
                .addHeader("Connection", "Keep-Alive")
                .url(url)
                .put(RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/octet-stream"), file))
                .build();

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .connectTimeout(1000, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(1000, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(3000, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .proxy(proxy)
                .proxyAuthenticator(proxyAuthenticator)
                .addNetworkInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
                    @Override public okhttp3.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                        okhttp3.Response originalResponse = chain.proceed(chain.request());
                        return originalResponse.newBuilder()
                                .body(new ProgressResponseBody(originalResponse.body(), progressListener))
                                .build();
                    }
                })
                .build();

        okhttp3.Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();

        responseCode = response.code();
        Log.d("Response code : ", " " + response.code());
        Log.d("DXXXXXX", " URL  1  ->    " + url);
        success = true;
        buffer = null;

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        // Handle the error
        Log.d(TAG, "Error: " + ex.getLocalizedMessage());
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }


} catch (Exception e) {

    e.printStackTrace();
}
return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should enable the progress bar first, just before calling the okhttp3 processing. Then, on response and on error, you should dismiss it.
Here's the snippet (I don't know okhttp but I've used volley many times. This example was kept simple enough to let you understand what I mean.)

```
sendJsonRequest(){

 //enable progress bar here
enableProgressBar();        
JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL, null,

new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
@Override
public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
    // dismiss it
     hideProgressDialog();  
     System.out.println(response);
 }
},
new Response.ErrorListener() {
@Override
public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
     // dismiss it and/or handle errors
     hideProgressDialog();
     // ...
}
});
queue.add(jsObjRequest);

}
```

Comment: Why did you give such a straight Volley's solution.